# Im unable to find the error with mysql code

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am newbie. i am not able to insert data from front end into mysql database. I am facing the problem at the time of insertion.

**my index.js code**

**I'm storing the form details in a variable and trying to insert it into database**

```
router.post('/signup',function(req,res,next) {
    var item = req.body;
    connection.connect(function(err){
        var sql = "INSERT INTO details VALUES ? ";
        connection.query(sql,[item]);
    });
    res.render('data' ,{items:item});
});
```

**Error message**

```
/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`name` = 'Gayathri', `pwd` = 'def'' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Connection.query (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:208:25)
    at Handshake._callback (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/routes/index.js:46:14)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:88:24)
    at /home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:225:14
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! jsonhbs@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the jsonhbs@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gayathri/.npm/_logs/2017-10-18T03_54_05_403Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What, _exactly_, is the content of `req.body`?  And what is the MySQL output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE details`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not valid SQL syntax. You can't use a placeholder for a bunch of values like that, you must break them out individually:

```
connection.query(
  "INSERT INTO details (name, pwd) VALUES (?,?)",
  [ "Name", "Pwd" ]
);
```

Supplying all those conditions as a single placeholder has the effect of encapsulating them inside a string, which breaks the syntax.

**IMPORTANT**: Always hash your passwords, never use plain-text to store them. At the absolute least [use Bcrypt](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/hashing-passwords-with-nodejs-and-bcrypt) which is specifically intended for passwords and not some high-speed hash like SHA1 or a compromised hash like MD5.

If you're using Node you probably want to at least consider using [Passport](http://passportjs.org) which can do a lot of the heavy lifting for you, and plays nicely with other Node components.